# Como convertir una tabla a un IEnumerable para mostrarla en un Dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework

Buen Dia, estoy aprendiendo c# ASP .NET MVC,
Como se puede convertir una tabla a un `IEnumerable` para utlizarla en un `Dropdownlistfor`?:
Tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
public class Saleform
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SaleaccountID { get; set; }
        public int LeadsourceID { get; set; }
        public int SalestageID { get; set; }
        public int VerifyCodeViewModelCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Likely { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dateup { get; set; }
        public virtual Salestage Salestage { get; set; }
        public virtual Leadsource Leadsource { get; set; }
        public virtual Saleaccount Saleaccount { get; set; }
    }
```

En otro archivo tengo el modelo referenciado:

```
public class Leadsource
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Saleform> Forms { get; set; }
}
```

En el controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
          IEnumerable<Leadsource> Ileadsourcelist = (from x in db.Leadsources 
          select x).ToList<Leadsource>();
          ViewData["Leadsourcenamelist"] = Ileadsourcelist;
          return View();
}
```

En la vista:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LeadsourceID, 
   (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Leadsourcenamelist"])
```

El error que marca es que no puede convertir la información de tipo `List` a tipo `IEnumerable`.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un `SelectList` a partir de una Lista de la tabla

```
List<Tabla> lista = (from r in context.NombreTabla orderby r.campoordenar select r).ToList();

SelectList select = new SelectList(lista, "nombreCampoValor", "nombreCampoDescripcion");

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.atributoModel, select, otros atributos);
```

Normalmente el SelectList lo implemento en un método dentro del Modelo

```
public SelectList getSelectList(){
  return new SelectList(lista, "nombreCampoValor", "nombreCampoDescripcion");
}
```

y en la vista

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.atributoModel, Model.getSelectList(), otros atributos);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Me sirvio tu sugerencia. Quedo asi: IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Ileadsourcelist = new SelectList(db.Leadsources.ToList(), "ID", "Name");

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

En tu *Controller* prueba con lo siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   IEnumerable<Leadsource> Ileadsourcelist = db.Leadsources.AsEnumerable(); // <<<-- Este es el cambio
   ViewData["Leadsourcenamelist"] = Ileadsourcelist;
   return View();
}
```

En lo personal prefiero usar `List`; tal que te sugiero usar:

```
List<Leadsource> Ileadsourcelist = db.Leadsources.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias. Ya quedo resuelto:
 IEnumerable Ileadsourcelist = new SelectList(db.Leadsources.ToList(), "ID", "Name"); 
 ViewData["Leadsourcenamelist"] = Ileadsourcelist;